# Training data for UnigramTagger= Brown corpus , testing data = new sentences tagged by nltk.pos_tag

Tags: machine-learning, nltk, pos-tagger

Kindly let me know if we can train the UnigramTagger with brown corpus and evaluate the same UnigramTagger on the testing data which was tagged using nltk.pos_tag?

if Yes, how do we interpret the accuracy?

CODE SNIP

```
**data3 = []
for i in data:
    data3.append(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(i.lower())))

brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories = ['news'])
unigram_tagger_brown = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_sents)
accuracy_value = unigram_tagger_brown.evaluate(data3)
print("Unigram Tagger Accuracy for brown is ",accuracy_value)**
```

Comment: can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It is unclear what you want to do, or what you have tried to achieve your goal.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy, I am trying to train the Unigram tagger using the brown corpus, instead of a using the same brown corpus for testing purpose.. i have used the nltk.pos_tag's output as a testing data to evaluate the Unigram tagger. I wanted to know what i am doing is right?

Comment: what does it output and `**data` is not correct python syntax. what errors are you getting?